# Windows 7 Trigger.io Error: environment can only contain strings

Tags: trigger.io

Running newly installed Trigger.io on hello world app in Windows 7 and I get this upon doing:

```
    forge run web


File "C:\Users\john.jesus\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\async.py", line 96, in run
result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\john.jesus\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\main.py", line 437, in run
build_to_run=build_to_run,
File "C:\Users\john.jesus\forge-workspace\helloworld\.template\generate_dynamic\customer_goals.py", line 124, in run_app
build_to_run.run()
File "C:\Users\john.jesus\forge-workspace\helloworld\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 337, in run
self._call_with_params(task_method, task_args)
File "C:\Users\john.jesus\forge-workspace\helloworld\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 296, in _call_with_params
return method(self, *params)
File "C:\Users\john.jesus\forge-workspace\helloworld\.template\generate_dynamic\web_tasks.py", line 141, in run_web
env=dict(os.environ, PORT=str(port), FORGE_DEBUG='1'))
File "C:\Users\john.jesus\forge-workspace\helloworld\.template\generate_dynamic\web_tasks.py", line 98, in _node
run_shell(node, *args, **kw)
File "C:\Users\john.jesus\forge-workspace\helloworld\.template\generate_dynamic\utils.py", line 338, in run_shell
raise state.error

TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

Comment: This may be related to [Why does Popen fail on Windows if the “env” parameter contains a unicode object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12253014/1309332). Do you, perchance, have any unicode objects in your environ?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - seems to be because Python can't cope with unicode in the environment dictionary for POpen. Bit more info here:

[Why does Popen fail on Windows if the "env" parameter contains a unicode object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253014/why-does-popen-fail-on-windows-if-the-env-parameter-contains-a-unicode-object)

I edited

C:\Users\mattc\forge-workspace\prototype-app.template\generate_dynamic\module_dynamic\utils.py

And changed line 304 to remove the passing of the environment variable, so that I had:

state.proc = lib.PopenWithoutNewConsole(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=None, preexec_fn=preexec_fn)

then my forge-web worked and I was able to run it. Not entirely sure this is the 'correct' fix, though, but it gets it going.

Answer (score -1):

Are you escaping slashes when pointing to files? ex: C:\folder\filename instead of C:\folder\filename?

Comment: file locations are duplicate