# python subprocess custom ENV = environment can only contain strings error

Tags: python, string, subprocess

I am trying to open a file with a program using:

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files\\.....\\rizomuv.exe" "c:\\users\\.....\\temp\\ODRizomExport.obj"'
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env['LMX_LICENSE_PATH'] = 'xxxx@xx.x.x.xxx'
subprocess.Popen(cmd, env = my_env)
```

I need to specify the license server for the software to open, but no matter what I do I keep getting the error:

```
# TypeError: environment can only contain strings #
```

It doesn't matter if I only pass the license env path or if I pass the whole os.env + licence path. It still won't continue.

What am I missing here?
I am runnign python from Maya, trying to get my geo into a RizomUV, but RizomUV needs that floating license server location to start.

I realize that my problem may be related to this: [Why does Popen fail on Windows if the "env" parameter contains a unicode object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253014/why-does-popen-fail-on-windows-if-the-env-parameter-contains-a-unicode-object/47798162)
but I am unsure about how I can apply this to my very simple script.

Bjorn

Comment: If you print `my_env`, are there any non-string values in it?

Comment: share the full stacktrace please

Comment: divide-and-conquer: what happens if you omit the 3rd line, i.e. just pass `env=os.environ.copy()` to `subprocess`? It would be weird if `os.environ` itself contained mappings with non-strings, but could indicate something already messed up before that point.

Comment: Just a tip: without the `shell=True` option, `cmd` should be a list of strings: `cmd=["C:\\Program Files\\.....\\rizomuv.exe", "c:\\users\\.....\\temp\\ODRizomExport.obj"] ; subprocess.Popen(cmd, env = my_env)`

Comment: my_env contains a dictionary I think:
# Result: {'ADSKFLEX_LICENSE_FILE': '@10.0.1.251',
 'ADSK_CLM_WPAD_PROXY_CHECK': 'FALSE',
 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData',
 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\bjorns\\AppData\\Roaming',
 'ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH': 'C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Arnold/maya2020/shaders;C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Arnold/maya2020/procedurals',
 'ASL.LOG': 'Destination=file'.... etc

Comment: If I omit line 3 and only pass os.environ I get the same error still.

Comment: Full stack trace:
# Error: environment can only contain strings
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\bin\python27.zip\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
#     errread, errwrite)
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\bin\python27.zip\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
#     startupinfo)
# TypeError: environment can only contain strings #

Comment: ok, so that (the fact that just passing `os.environ` without mod results in the same error) means that your `os.environ` is already screwed up by the time you reach the code in your question. I would consider revising the question altogether, e.g.: "how is it possible that my `os.environ` contains non-string elements".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like the OP's environment itself is already damaged (contains non-`str` keys and/or values) before the code in question, or, as the OP suggests, may contain non-ascii characters (an issue on Windows), as simply calling `subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=os.environ)` reportedly also raises the same error.

You can check that a value is an ASCII string with the following:

```
def is_ascii(s):
    try:
        s.encode('ascii')
        return True
    except (AttributeError, UnicodeEncodeError):
        return False
```

This returns `True` only if `s` is a string and does not contain any non-ASCII chars.

For example:

```
assert is_ascii('hello')
assert is_ascii('')
assert not is_ascii(1)
assert not is_ascii('été')
```

**Application 1: find offending key/values**:

```
{k: v for k, v in os.environ.items() if not (is_ascii(k) and is_ascii(v))}
```

**Application 2: your code, using a subset of your env for the subprocess**:

```
my_env = {k: v for k, v in os.environ.items() if is_ascii(k) and is_ascii(v)}
my_env['LMX_LICENSE_PATH'] = 'xxxx@xx.x.x.xxx'
subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=my_env)
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre, you are right.
Turns out that MAYA 2020 is unicode, 2020 is a number and not string.
I converted it to string like this:
    import os
    my_env = os.environ.copy()
    for e in my_env:
        if not 'str' in str(type(my_env[e])):
            my_env[e] = str(my_env[e])